# How can I loop thru this array to get what I need?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with the twitter API to retrieve all of my tweets. However, I can't seem to get the "expanded_url" and "hashtag" properties. The documentation for this particular API can be found at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline. My code is as follows:

```
$retweets = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?  include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=callmedan';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $retweets);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlout = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($curlout, true);
$tweet_number = count($response);

for($i = 0;$i < $tweet_number;$i++)
{
    $url = $response['entities']['urls'];
    $hashtag = $response['entities']['hashtags'];
    $text = $response[$i]['text'];

    echo "$url <br />";
    echo "$hashtag <br />";
    echo "$text <br />";
    echo "<br /><br />";

}
```

I get an error message reading "Notice: Undefined index: entities."

Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo var_dump($response);` and make sure you're accessing the data you think is in there (make sure the indexes exist in the array). It's also a good way to visually see what you're trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should do (if $response is an array you must access the proper index):

```
$url = $response[$i]['entities']['urls'];
$hashtag = $response[$i]['entities']['hashtags'];
$text = $response[$i]['text'];
```

Otherwise use foreach:

```
foreach ($response as $r){
    $url = $r['entities']['urls'];
    $hashtag = $r['entities']['hashtags'];
    $text = $r['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an integer-incremented for loop, but not utilizing the `$i` index.  Instead, use a `foreach`:

```
foreach($response as $tweet)
{
    $url = $tweet['entities']['urls'];
    $hashtag = $tweet['entities']['hashtags'];
    $text = $tweet['text'];

    echo "$url <br />";
    echo "$hashtag <br />";
    echo "$text <br />";
    echo "<br /><br />";

}
```